# Apache2 Disallow access to the whole server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, apache-2.4

On my VPS, I want to block access of certain IP addresses to the whole server.

I have for example these websites (document roots)

```
/var/www #the VPS website itself
/home/eve/www/evesite.com
/home/adam/www/adamsite.com
```

I edited the '/etc/apache2/apache2.conf' and added this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        deny from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX #IP to ban
</Directory>
```

but this only works for the '/var/www'.

I know I can go and edit all the conf files in the 'sites-enabled' folder but I want to do this at a **single location**.

Also if I want to block a whole range of IP addresses, ege 123.123.123.[0-255], how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On my VPS, I want to block access of certain IP addresses to the whole server.

Use a firewall e.g.

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.0.2.1 -j DROP
```

or

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.0.2.1 -p tcp  --dport 80 -j DROP
```

> Also if I want to block a whole range of IP addresses, ege 123.123.123.[0-255], how would I do it?

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.0.2.0/24 -j DROP
```

or

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.0.2.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```